# Sending Post Data via LWP (Request built by HTTP::Request) for Spotify API

Tags: perl, spotify

See: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

I'm using the "client credentials flow" method.

```
sub get_token {
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $SPOTIFY_TOKEN);
    $req->header('Authorization' => 'Basic MYBASE64HERE');

    my $post_data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
    $req->content($post_data);
    my $resp = $ua->request($req); #this is LWP
    if ($resp->is_success) {
        my $token = $resp->decoded_content;
        print "$token\n";
        return \$token;
    }
    else {
        print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
        print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
    }
}
```

I get back `HTTP POST error code: 400 / bad request`

I know that it doesn't have to do with the header information or the URL. I tested via Curl and used Data::Dumper to verify it was formatted properly.

I'm not sure on the format I need to send the POST body data. I've tried the example above `my $post_data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';` as well as every variation I could think of. Is there a proper way to do this in Perl using HTPP::Request to build the POST request?

Comment: Does anything change if you do: `my $resp = $ua->post($SPOTIFY_URL_INCLUDING_TOKEN, 'Authorization' => 'Basic MYBASE64HERE', Content => { grant_type => 'client_credentials' });`?

Answer (score 0):

I think following should work, Please try:
`$req->content(grant_type => 'client_credentials');`

Answer (score 0):

my $post_data = "grant_type=client_credentials";

Turns out this is the answer. I'm not sure how I missed this previously.